# sqlalchemy concat with more than 2 elements on Oracle DB

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sqlalchemy, concatenation

considering the following table definition

```
meta = MetaData()

tgd = Table('T_GROUP_DAT', meta,
            Column('C_ID'),
            Column('CLASS_CODE'))
```

I create a select-statement using the `sqlalchemy.sql.functions.concat` with 3 statements

```
tgd_q1 = select([functions.concat(tgd.c.C_ID, '-', tgd.c.CLASS_CODE)])
```

using

```
tgd_q1.compile(dialect=OracleDialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
```

the query

```
SELECT concat("T_GROUP_DAT"."C_ID", "T_GROUP_DAT"."CLASS_CODE") AS concat_1
FROM "T_GROUP_DAT"
```

is generated. However, when I run this, the exception `ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments` is thrown. This is because CONCAT (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) only allows 2 Arguments.

My workaround for now ist to use concat inside of concat, which works

```
tgd_q1 = select([functions.concat(functions.concat(tgd.c.C_ID,'-'),tgd.c.CLASS_CODE)])
```

However, this makes the resulting sql-query far less readable. Is there a way to create a query using `|` oparator or to create a more readable sql query for this case using sqlalchemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a concat with more than 2 parameters `+` operator can be used:

```
tgd_q1 = select([tgd.c.C_ID + '-' + tgd.c.CLASS_CODE])
```

resulting in a `||` connected query like this

```
select c_id || '-' || class_code from t
```

Comment: For the record, this answer is also valid on sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, [CONACT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) function only takes 2 values.

It is easy to use `||` to concat any number of the column as follows:

```
select col1 || ' ' || col2 || ' ' || col3 ...
from your_table;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: thanks for your answer. What I meant was how I would create a statement like yours using sqlalchemy in pyhton. I clearified the question.